# Are there any issues/best practices/suggestions when working with a DataDistribution instead of a distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

Suppose there is a random variable $X$ that can take on values $-1,0,1$, with probabilities $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=.25$ and $P(X=0)=.5$.

How can I work with such a random variable in mathematica? (Find the mean, transform it -- for example by adding it to another random variable -- etc).

The `EmpiricalDistribution` command seems to do this, but creates a `DataDistribution` instead of distribution.

So my question is whether using `EmpiricalDistribution` is the correct way to model such a random variable, and if so is there downfalls/issues that `DataDistribution` objects have that typical distributions dont? (For example, perhaps they are much slower?)

(Aside: Instead of a random variable $X$ taking on 3 values, a more practical example is perhaps a distribution for a "weighted/damaged" dice that has $0$ probability of showing 6, and $1/3$ probability of showing 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only address your first question "How can I work with such a random variable in mathematica? (Find the mean, transform it -- for example by adding it to another random variable -- etc)."

Despite me not liking the name of 'EmpiricalDistribution` for dealing with legitimate discrete distributions, going that route seems to allow the use of most of *Mathematica*'s random variable functions.  (But despite using *Mathematica* for quite some time, there is so much I don't know about it.)

```
d1 = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/4, 1/2, 1/4} -> {-1, 0, 1}];
d2 = EmpiricalDistribution[{1/8, 1/2, 1/8, 1/4} -> {-1, 0, 1/2, 1}];

dSum = TransformedDistribution[x1^2 + 7 Cos[x2], {x1 \[Distributed] d1, x2 \[Distributed] d2}];

Mean[dSum]
(* Oops, this doesn't work *)
```

[image: Output of Mean[dSum]]

```
Expectation[z, z \[Distributed] dSum]
(* 4 + 7/8 Cos[1/2] + (21 Cos[1])/8 *)

Expectation[z^2, z \[Distributed] dSum]
(* 1/16 (652 + 14 Cos[1/2] + 91 Cos[1] + 147 Cos[2]) *)

PDF[dSum, z]
```

[image: PDF of dSum]

```
SeedRandom[12345];
RandomVariate[dSum, 25]
(* {1 + 7 Cos[1], 7 Cos[1], 8, 7 Cos[1], 1 + 7 Cos[1/2], 7, 
 7 Cos[1], 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7 Cos[1], 7, 7, 7 Cos[1], 8, 
 7 Cos[1], 8, 7, 7, 1 + 7 Cos[1/2], 7 Cos[1], 8, 7} *)
```